# Express + React + Electron : Express does not work after building exe file

Tags: node.js, express, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

We have created a Desktop app using Electron Js. We have also added **React Js and Express Js for the front end and the backend**. Everything works fine before building an exe file but **when I build the executable file for windows Everything works fine except Express Js.**

*The command I run :*

```bash
"package-win": "electron-packager . demo --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName='demo'"
```

**Main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const appExpress = express();

// Define your Express.js routes here
appExpress.get('/api/message', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ message: 'Hello from Express.js backend!' });
});

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true, // Enable Node.js integration in the renderer process
        },
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

    // Change the directory to your backend folder
    const backendPath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'backend');

    console.log(backendPath);
    // Run the Express.js server from the backend folder
    const backendProcess = require('child_process').spawn('node', [path.join(backendPath, 'backend.js')]);

    backendProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`Backend: ${data}`);
    });

    backendProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`Backend Error: ${data}`);
    });

}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

*Package.json file*

```json
{
  "name": "zzz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "foo",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . demo --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName='demo'"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.myapp",
    "directories": {
      "output": "release-builds"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "backend",
        "to": "backend"
      },
      {
        "from": "db.db",
        "to": "db.db"
      }
    ],
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3",
    "electron": "^25.3.2"
  }
}
```

The Directory

[image: Directory]